# Mapping enums onto database in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, enums, grails-orm

My grails app uses a lot of enums, but the current GORM solution for enums isn't very satisfactory because it implies the data is in the code, since GORM doesn't map enums into the database.

Previously we used a big table containing different types of enumerations, e.g.: county and city selection in one table. Hence the table in database would contain 3 columns: the enum type (county or city), id and name (which county or city).

Right now I'd like to switch them to real enums, but it just seems unlikely with GORM. I tried to do it with transients in the domain class, but AFAIK it still requires you to have a static enum already present for the class to refer to.

I'm completely lost here, could anybody hint me from where or which function I might get what I wanted ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply, do not use Enums for data which is not static and unlikely to change. Instead, use regular domain classes and bootstrap the required data.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I guess joining tables is inevitable after all.

Comment: Yes, but GORM will do it for you and SQL is pretty good handling those these days so this should not be a problem AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code is what you want:

```
enum UserOrderState
{
    WAITCHECK("Ожидает проверки"),
    INWORK("Выполняется"),
    DONE("Выполнен"),
    CANCELED("Отменен"),
    NOPRODUCT("Нет в наличии")

    String name

    UserOrderState(String name)
    {
        this.name = name
    }

    static list()
    {
        [ WAITCHECK, INWORK, DONE, CANCELED, NOPRODUCT ]
    }
}
```

Then in .gsp you can make combobox this way:

```
<g:select 
    name="state" 
    from="${internetshop.UserOrderState.list()}" 
    value="${fieldValue(bean: order, field: 'state')}" 
    optionValue="name" 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is what I trying to avoid: data in code.

Comment: But this the only way to code with enums in domain. Another way is to make domain UserOrderState for example.